# Add a variable inside Additional data source expressions in Alfresco process services

Tags: variables, mapping, alfresco, aps, juel

I am trying to add a variable inside Additional data source expressions for document generator in Alfresco

I have this taskid variable and when i put it it doesnt work.

here is what works:

`${transdataService.getData("DocName","55280"})}` It works and

`${transdataService.getData("DocName",${taskid})}` doesnt and i get this error in logs:

> Error parsing '${transdataService.getData("DocName",${taskid})}':
>   lexical error at position 38, encountered invalid character '{',
>   expected expression token     at
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.Builder.build(Builder.java:97)  at
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.TreeStore.get(TreeStore.java:61)

Answer (score 0):

For passing variable inside expressions (`${expression}`), you do not require another expression tag as nested expressions are not allowed. To access a variable inside an expression, simply pass your variable literal as-is like `${transdataService.getData("DocName",taskid)}`

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct thank you, please as an extra information when it worked i tried the same thing in another process with same data i got this error :

<</foreach>>